# SQL Server : aggregate by month with gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sequence, gaps-and-islands

I need some help to aggregate some data. Imagine I have the following table:

```
            Employee    Reference Period
            123440      20141201
            123440      20150101
            123440      20150201
            123440      20150301
            123440      20160201
            123440      20160301
            123440      20160401
            123440      20160501
            123440      20160601
            123440      20160701
            123440      20160801
            123440      20160901
            123440      20161001
            123442      20141201
            123442      20150101
            123442      20150201
            123442      20150301
            123442      20150401
            123442      20150501
            123442      20150601
            123442      20150701
            123442      20150801
            123442      20150901
            123442      20151001
            123442      20151101
            123442      20151201
            123442      20170301
            123442      20170401
            123442      20170501
            123442      20170601
            123442      20170701
            123442      20170801
            123442      20170901
            123442      20171001
            123442      20171101
            123442      20171201
```

I need a SQL query to output the following:

```
Employee    From_Date   To_Date
123440      20141201    20150301
123440      20160201    20161001
123442      20141201    20151201
123442      20170301    20171201
```

Basically what I need is to join the rows with no month gaps and return the `[From Date]` as MIN() in the sequence and the `[To Date]` as MIN() in the sequence. Anyone can help me?

I try to do the following query:

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT [Employee], t1refer, t2refer, DIFF,
                Grp2 = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition BY [Employee],DIFF ORDER BY t1refer),
                Grp = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition BY [Employee],DIFF ORDER BY t1refer) - DIFF
          FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.[Employee], t1.[Reference Period] t1refer , t2.[Reference Period] t2refer, DATEDIFF(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(t2.[Reference Period]+'01'),101)),CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(t1.[Reference Period]+'01'),101))) AS DIFF
            FROM MyTable t1 
                CROSS APPLY 
                (SELECT TOP 1 t.[Reference Period] FROM MyTable t 
                    WHERE t.[Employee] = t1.[Employee] AND CONVERT(date,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(t.[Reference Period]+'01'),101)) < CONVERT(date,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(t1.[Reference Period]+'01'),101)) ORDER BY t.[Reference Period] DESC) t2
            ) QRY
            )
        SELECT [Employee],
       [From Date] = MIN(t2refer),
       [To Date] = MAX(t1refer)     
         FROM CTE   
         GROUP BY [Employee], DIFF
```

Note that the database is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: check the updated code..original code has issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another classic *gaps and island* problem

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT a.*,
                Prev_period = b.[Reference Period]
         FROM   Yourtable a
                LEFT JOIN Yourtable b
                       ON a.Employee = b.Employee
                          AND Dateadd(mm, 1, b.[Reference Period]) = a.[Reference Period])
SELECT Employee,
       From_Date = Min([Reference Period]),
       To_Date = Max([Reference Period])
FROM   cte a
       CROSS apply(SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN [Reference Period] = Dateadd(mm, 1, Prev_period) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                   FROM   cte b
                   WHERE  a.Employee = b.Employee
                          AND a.[Reference Period] >= b.[Reference Period]) cs (grp)
GROUP  BY Employee,
          grp
```

- **[Demo](http://rextester.com/QTCK37121)**

Comment: This answer has been marked as accepted, but I'm sure this only seems to work because of the coincidence in the OP's example data. It is indeed a gaps and islands problem, but the `DENSE_RANK` needs to be replaced with something that translates the month into an integer, that has stepping of 1 per month (so that discontinuities show against the purely sequential `ROW_NUMBER`). It also needs to be partitioned by employee in the same way that the `ROW_NUMBER` is.

Comment: @Steve - Updated... check now